# HTML5 video - Get only soundtrack from video

Tags: html, audio, video

I would like to load a video where I only present the sound of the video to the user. In fact if I could only download the sound track from the video, it would be best.

Is it possible to load a video with the  tag and then only get the sound?

The videos are encoded into H.264 codec in .m4v or .mp4 file extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think downloading only the sound track is not possible, so you have to play the video anyway, but you can hide it.

You can use a js-library (such as jplayer or videojs, so you have the controls) and remove the video via css.

Have a look at this js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Hm6y/

Insert the plugin into the Head of your document:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.1/video.js"></script>
```

The HTML where you specify the source files:

```
<video id="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" data-setup='{"controls": true}'>
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
```

The CSS:

```
#vjs_video_4_html5_api {  
    display:none; /* remove video */
}
.vjs-big-play-button {
    display:none !important;  /* remove play button inside video*/
}

#vjs_video_4{
    height:38px !important;  /* make container smaller */
}

.vjs-control-bar {  /* make controlbar visible */
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition-duration: 0s!important;
    display:block !important;
}
```

In this case I used videojs so I have the controls for the video, then I hid the video with css. Feel free to adapt the css to your needs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)

I will try some of your suggestions when we are gonna develop that module.